# Memory leak c++/cli method

Tags: .net, opencv, visual-c++, memory-leaks, c++-cli

It looks like this method is creating a memory leak when called. If I don't call it, there's no memory leak.
Any idea what's causing it?

The function is part of a c++/cli dll that is being called by a c# app.

```
List<array<Byte>^>^ writejpeg( cv::Mat ovrImagePrevious, List<array<Byte>^>^ overviewOneImages, Dictionary<String^,List<array< Byte >^>^>^ violationAssets, String ^ value, int fileCorruptFlag ) 
{
    vector<uchar> buf1;//buffer for coding
    vector<int> param = vector<int>(2);
    param[0]=CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;
    param[1]=100;//default(95) 0-100
    int img_sz1=ovrImagePrevious.cols*ovrImagePrevious.rows;
    array <Byte>^ hh1 = gcnew array<Byte> (img_sz1);

    if (fileCorruptFlag==1)
    {img_sz1=1;
    hh1=nullptr;}
    else
    {

    cv::imencode(".jpeg", ovrImagePrevious, buf1, param);
    for(int i=0; i <  buf1.size(); i++)
        {
        hh1[i] = buf1[i];
        }

    }

    if(!violationAssets->TryGetValue(value, overviewOneImages))
    {
        overviewOneImages = gcnew List<array<Byte>^>();
        violationAssets->Add(value, overviewOneImages);
    }

    overviewOneImages->Add(hh1);

    return overviewOneImages;


}
```

UPDATE#1:

When I remove this line:

```
overviewOneImages->Add(hh1);
```

the leak goes away.

I need to do this line differently. Any ideas?

UPDATE#2:

It turns out the leak happens when the function is called in that part of the code

```
    if(!violationAssets->TryGetValue("OVERVIEW_ONE", overviewOneImages))
    {
        cv::Mat f1;
        captureOverview>>ovrImageCurrent; 

        if (fileCorruptFlag==0)
            f1= ovrImageCurrent;

        if (windowOn && !fileCorruptFlag)
        {
            cv::namedWindow( "Frame1", 1 ); 
            cv::imshow( "Frame1", f1 );  
            cv::waitKey(1);
        }

    overviewOneImages = writejpeg(f1, overviewOneImages,   violationAssets,"OVERVIEW_ONE",fileCorruptFlag);


    }
```

and it looks like it's due the line

```
       f1= ovrImageCurrent;
```

Changing it to

```
       ovrImageCurrent.copyTo(f1)
```

fixes it.

Any idea why the first is incorrect and cannot be disposed? Also is there a better way to fix it?

Comment: How do you know there's a memory leak? Maybe the garbage collector just hasn't collected the gcnew'd objects yet?

Comment: How did you detect th memory leak ? How fast is it growing ? What is the context of this function call ? (eg how many alls are you making to it ...)

Comment: In task manager, I watch the memory for that process. I have the app calling the dll in a loop. The memory increases by 0.5mb to 1mb every call. If I dont call that function  in the DLL it does not increase.

Comment: The memory allocated in gc heap will be released at garbage collection circular, that's not memory leak. If you like to handle it yourself, just `delete` it rather than `hh1=nullptr;`.

Comment: Should it get automatically released after every call of the dll?

Comment: No, we don't know/care when the gc releases memory. If you are interesting, you could study the mechanism of gc.

Comment: The garbage collector must run when the system cannot commit more virtual memory to the process, for example, the disk is full. Running earlier is a matter of process performance design. It need never release any memory, doing so is only for system performance. To do so, it must move object around in memory, which reduces process performance.

Answer (score 5):

Greatly simplified, your code looks like this:

```
hh1 = allocate a bunch of memory
add hh1 to overviewOneImages
return overviewOneImages
```

Every time you call that function, assuming that `hh1` isn't set to `null`, you're going to eat a little more memory. After all, your `overviewOneImages` list maintains a reference to the allocated memory, so the garbage collector can't free it.

In addition, there is code that will allocate a new list in some situations, and that list gets added to the `violationAssets` dictionary. Again, the dictionary maintains a reference to the allocated memory, so the garbage collector can't release it.

You need to remove things from your list (or dictionary) when you're done using them.

Comment: @fmvpsenior: I have no idea what you're trying to do, so I can't provide any suggestions for a better way.

Comment: It's this line
overviewOneImages->Add(hh1);

Comment: I'm trying to see how I can add hh1 without creating a leak

Comment: @fmvpsenior: I don't understand how you expect to allocate memory, return a reference to said memory, and somehow have that memory released at the same time. One would assume that you're adding `hh1` to the list because you're going to use it later. That's not a "leak", but normal behavior. Perhaps the problem is that the caller is using the memory and then not releasing it (i.e. removing it from the list)?

Comment: You mean the app calling the DLL should release it?

Comment: If the app is done using the array then, yes, the app should remove it from the list.